# Passing dynamic data to Jquery Highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am using jquery Highcharts plugin to show charts on web page and facing difficulties to pass dynamic data to chart series data. Code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var data = {!!$data!!};
var result = [];

for(var i in data)
    result.push([i,data[i]]);

var review_sites = JSON.stringify(result);      
alert(review_sites);

    // Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('site_distribution', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Reviews Distribution By Site'
    },
    //subtitle: {
      //  text: 'Click the slices to view versions. Source: <a href="http://statcounter.com" target="_blank">statcounter.com</a>'
    //},
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}: {point.y} reviews'
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '{point.y} of {point.total} reviews<br><b>{point.percentage:.1f} %</b>'
    },

    series: [{
      type: 'pie',
      name: 'Sites',
      data:  
    }],

});

</script>
```

How to pass `review_sites` to `series: [{
      type: 'pie',
      name: 'Sites',
      data:

    }],`

I want to pass review_sites value to above one code. For now I leave data:

Comment: How the `review_sites` variable looks like? Could you change the `alert()` to `console.log(review_sites)` and provide me with the result?

Comment: @daniel_s Problem solved bro, Thanks for your response.